# soft keyboard covers edittexts, scroll view doesnt work

Tags: android, scrollview, android-edittext

I have few editText in ScrollView. If there are many editTexts, and they exceed the display, everything works fine, but if they doesnt, and soft keyboard is opened, I cant scroll it(keyboard covers few of them). My layout:

```
 <ScrollView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"   
    >
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: add this property to Edittext 
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

Answer (score 1):

I added this field in the ScrollView tag:

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use windowSoftInputMode attribute for your activity and set it to "adjustResize". This will make room for your soft keyboard.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the "windowSoftInputMode" for the activity in your manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I would try that.